# Sorting arrays by largest to smallest numbers with Ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, sorting

I need to create an Ajax/Jquery call that will sort an array(https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime) from smallest to largest using the "alltime" var in the array.

```
 $("#start").click(function(){
  function SortByalltime(a, b) {
    var aNum = a.alltime.sort();
    var bNum = b.alltime.sort();
    return ((aNum < bNum) ? -1 : ((aNum > bNum) ? 1 : 0));
  }
  $.get("https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent", function(data) {

    //here we run the function to sort the array of data before transforming it to table
    data.sort(SortByalltime);
    var table = '<table>'
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      table += '<tr><td>' + data[i].alltime + '</td><td><img width=20 height=20 src="' + data[i].img + '"></td><td>' + data[i].lastUpdate + '</td><td>' + data[i].recent + '</td><td>' + data[i].username + '</td></tr>';

    }
    $('body').append(table);
  }); 
 });
```

Here is my current call, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

`alltime` is an **integer** rather than an **array**

So simply replace

```
var aNum = a.alltime.sort();
var bNum = b.alltime.sort();
```

with

```
var aNum = a.alltime;
var bNum = b.alltime;
```

For smallest to largest

```
  function SortByalltime(a, b) {
    return (a.alltime - b.alltime);
  }
```

For largest to smallest

```
  function SortByalltime(a, b) {
    return (b.alltime - a.alltime);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the property `alltime` for sorting.

```
function SortByalltime(a, b) {
    return b.alltime - a.alltime;
}
```